# How to directly write binary data in a file in c++

Tags: c++, compression, binaryfiles

I am working on a project (Huffman Coding), and here I am gonna need to write direct 1s and 0s to a binary file. How should I do it?

Comment: Take a look at `std::ofstream`.

Comment: There's no way to write individual bits to a file. You need to package them together into (at least) single bytes before writing them out.

Comment: Okay thanks that might work!

Answer (score 1):

You need to accumulate bits in an integer buffer, and then write out one byte once you have at least eight of them. E.g., initializing:

```
int buf = 1;
```

Insert one bit (`bit` must be 0 or 1):

```
buf = 2 * buf + bit;
if (buf > 255) {
    cout << (char)buf;
    buf = 1;
}
```

When you're done, make sure to write out any remaining bits at the end:

```
if (buf > 1)
    cout << buf;
```

Note that if you are on Windows, you must open your output file as binary (using `ios::out | ios::binary`), or convert it to binary mode after opening. For `cout` as used above, you can:

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
```